# SlideDirection in Sliding_Up_Panel flutter

Tags: flutter, sliding

I new flutter . I use lib https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel in my layout

When I drag and drop panel from the middle to the top -> panel will scroll to top ,
from the middle to the bottom -> panel will scroll panel to bottom.

Can I keep the panel in the middle when drag and drop it in the center? like this :

- https://media.giphy.com/media/151brg1VCvrTTMPheB/giphy.gif

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "snapPoint" option, like this:

```
SlidingUpPanel(
    ...
    snapPoint: 0.5, // Percentage where the panel stops (0.5 = 50%)
    ...
)
```